# Why is lapply not forwarding additional arguments?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, stringi

I have a big Dataset of Tweets where every row is one unique Tweet and I have a list of Keywords which I want to extract from these Tweets if one or more of them are present in the variable *text*. This List of Keywords has been compiled into a Regex-Expression (saved in the variable *search_key*) including some lookarounds and other conditions.

The extraction of strings works perfectly fine if the following code is used:

```
data$keyword <- stri_extract_all(str = data$text, regex = search_key)
```

But in order to optimize/parallelize the code, I would like to use functions from the apply family. But on execution of one of the following lines I always get an error because the *regex*-argument is not passed on to the *stri_extract_all*-function:

```
data$keyword <- lapply(data$text, FUN = stri_extract_all(), regex = search_key)
data$keyword <- lapply(data$text, FUN = stri_extract_all(), regex = get(search_key))
data$keyword <- lapply(data$text, FUN = stri_extract_all(), ... = "regex=search_key")
```

This behaviour occurs independent of the *search_key* and the content of the *text*-variable so any column of text and any working Regex can be used for testing. The following data is a simplified version of my data and can be used as well:

```
data <- structure(list(status_id = c(1112765520644894720, 1112938379296104448, 
1112587129622876160, 1113006196259196928, 1112840488208531456
), text = c("@LaraFukuro more frilly stuff but i actually found a matching carrot bag which also screamed \"LARA\" inside me xD", 
"@EuroMasochismo @VaeVictis @AlbertoBagnai @Comunardo La selezione fatta a dodici anni favorisce chi è seguito. È come selezionare a 4 anni chi deve giocare a pallone proibendolo a tutti gli altri ...", 
"@SignorErnesto @Cr1st14nM3s14n0 @ggargiulo3 @micheleboldrin Sbagliato io.", 
"@BrownResearchGT On Aconcagua, the permit requires climbers above basecamp to collect their waste and carry it back down where it's taken away by helicopter. They actually weigh the bag! And still, most small rocks had human feces underneath. It's a problem!\r\nHopefully @DenaliNPS will follow suit. ", 
"@Jenn198523 Once you silence a person &amp; cover them with a huge trash bag, beating &amp; killing are not far behind."
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

search_key <- "(?<=(^|\\s|\\D))([:alnum:]*|@[:alnum:]*|#[:alnum:]*)bag([:alnum:]*)(?=(\\D|\\s|$))"
```

**What mistake am I making and how could it be solved?**
Any advice on optimization of such tasks are of course welcome as well.

Comment: Remove the `()` like `lapply(data$text, FUN = stri_extract_all, regex = search_key)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stri_extract_all` is already vectorized on `str`. You do not need to enclose it in `lapply` and you will significantly slow down your code if you do so.

```
data$keyword <- stri_extract_all(data$text, regex = search_key)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I just noticed that it say so in the documentation.
Do you now of any ways to parallize vectorized functions? Or are there other ways of optimizing them?